# Induction in a first order system with ZF

Tags: set-theory, induction, first-order-logic

Suppose I have some characterization of the natural numbers $N$ in a first-order system under ZF.  To be precise, I have $N = \lbrace n: \forall w:( w\space is\space inductive) \rightarrow n \in w \rbrace $  and a predicate $P[x]$ such that $P[0]$ and $P[x] \rightarrow P[succ[x]] $.

Therefore, $n \in N \rightarrow n \in P[x]$, but I'd also like to show that $ n \in P[x]\rightarrow n \in N $.

I'm using Von Neumann ordinals ($succ(x) := \lbrace x \rbrace \cup x$), and I believe that the characterization is "sharp": $P[x] \equiv (x=0\vee \exists y:x=succ(y)) \wedge \forall y\in x:(y=0 \vee \exists z \in y : (y=succ(z)\wedge z \in x))$

Noting $x \notin N \wedge \exists y:x=succ(y) \rightarrow y \notin N$, and applying a first order induction "downward" to show some property $\phi$ over the $y : y \in x$ for some $x$ such that $P[x]$, I can construct the set for which $ \neg \phi[x] $, and reach a contradiction under the assumption $\neg \phi[0]$ by showing that set inductive, and therefore $\exists n : (n \in N \wedge \phi[n]) \rightarrow \phi[0]$

Obviously this will not be useful for $\phi[x] := x \in N$, however, since there is no such $n \notin N$!

So, is it possible to do this sort of thing?  How does one proceed?  Or are there models which have bigger $\lbrace x:P[x]\rbrace$ than $N$?

The alternative is to carry around the "$x \in N$" clause in sets defined by specification, such as the inductive restriction of $N$ by $P[x]$, $\lbrace x : x \in N \wedge P[x] \rbrace$ obtained to reach $n \in N \rightarrow P[n]$ above.  Which is not so bad, but $N = \lbrace x : P[x] \rbrace$ is cleaner.

Comment: You'll need to use the [Axiom of Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity). $\;$

Comment: It clearly requires regularity, sure.   The problem is that the proof is inductive, so in my first-order system the inductive set useful for proof always comes with a $x \in N$ tacked onto the specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note x∉N∧∃y:x=succ(y) → y∉N. P has the stronger property

P[x] → x=0 ∨ ∃y:x=succ(y) ∧ P[y].

Combining these and defining ϕ[x] := x∉N ∧ P[x], we get

ϕ[x] → ∃y:x=succ(y) ∧ ϕ[y]

If there exists x such that ϕ[x], let C = {y ∈ x : ϕ[y] ∧ y ⊂  x}.

C is non-empty as it contains the predecessor of x, but contradicts regularity as

$y \in C$ → ∃z:(y=succ(z) ∧ z ∈ $y \cap
 C)$

Hence there is no such x, and so P[x] → x∈N

Comment: David - It is not clear how to reach the first implication, is the problem.  In particular, I believe it requires an inductive proof.  Since there is only set-induction in my system (only the ZFC axioms, no special schema for induction on predicates), you can only show inductive sets (say those satisfying a specific property) which are subsets of $N$ are equal to $N$.   At this point there may clearly be inductive subsets that have some members outside of $N$, I wish to show that any object $x$ for which $P[x]$ is not in any of those.   Does this make sense?

Comment: By the "first implication" do you mean P[x] → x=0 ∨ ∃y:x=succ(y) ∧ P[y] ? I cannot see any need to use induction to prove that. From the first part of the definition of P[x] either x=0 or x=succ(y) for some y. In the latter case it then follows almost immediately from the second part of the definition that P[y], (just have to show z∈y rather than z∈x).

Comment: Supposing $P[x]$, if $x=0$ the result obviously follows.  Assuming ∃y:x=succ(y) then, we need to show  P[y] = (y=0∨∃z:y=succ(z))∧∀z∈y:(z=0∨∃w∈z:(z=succ(w)∧w∈y)).   $ y \in x $, however, so (y=0∨∃z∈y:(y=succ(z)∧z∈x)).  This gives us the first clause of $P[y]$, after showing as you say $z \in y $ (true, or else regularity is violated).  But what about ∀z∈y:(z=0∨∃w∈z:(z=succ(w)∧w∈y))?  This looks like bad news:  it involves a third "level" of the structure x which has not yet been constrained...

Comment: We also know $y \subset x$ so $z \in y \rightarrow z \in x$ and so ∀z∈y:(z=0∨∃w∈z:(z=succ(w)∧w∈x)). $w \neq y$ so $w \in y$.